# How do multiple devs use VSTest for a single C# project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vstest

We're using C# in VS2013 and the basic problem is unit tests aren't portable between dev stations or the build server. We have test runners, which are XML files generated by VS, but they contain absolute paths.

This is, of course, unacceptable, and it's unacceptable (or outright impossible) that each developer use the same file system or that we maintain a unique set of test runners for each developer and the build server.

What was MS thinking? Is there any way to make these test runners portable between workstations? Is there perhaps a sane way of generating test runners, perhaps as a build step?

EDIT: If it makes things clearer, ordered tests contain a "storage" attribute which are absolute paths to either other test runners or to the unit test dll. Ordered tests are our bread and butter here. Is there any way to fix this or is there a reasonable replacement? Suppose I could write an ordered test in C#? I'm new to the MS Test framework. One such file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderedTest name="submitthenfill" storage="c:\...\orderedtestrunners\general\submitthenfill.orderedtest" id="e571b9fd-81e3-4bcf-b9c2-ab077e6ef216" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
<TestLinks>
<TestLink id="159c8842-f452-4116-81f8-f91a59fcf79f" name="Setup_SubmitThenFill" storage="c:\...\bin\x64\debug\integration_tests.tests.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<TestLink id="fc1eb0d9-cf00-c324-e85c-545d1e5f0acf" name="SubmitLimit_Fill" storage="c:\...\bin\x64\debug\integration_tests.tests.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
<TestLink id="b230b0fa-d0ba-0462-849b-31a63461d1f2" name="SubmitEventLookup" storage="c:\...\bin\x64\debug\integration_tests.tests.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</TestLinks>
</OrderedTest>
```

I haven't found any means of specifying a relative path that makes it work.

Comment: Please be more clear? Exactly which scenario are you unable to use with multiple developers? I've had no problems there.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, ordered tests have a "storage" attribute and they are absolute paths, so when I check out the project from the repo, I can't run any of the tests.

Comment: Can you please add that to your question. You didn't mention ordered tests. Be certain to show where this "storage" attribute is at, and show that you cannot make that an absolute path.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can create the same paths by using virtual machines that are set up the same for each developer.  Another trick that can be used is to use the `subst` command to map a drive letter to a path, so that you can pretend the file system is the same.